# How to prevent GWT application cashing the css file in the html file

Tags: html, css, gwt

I am developing the GWT application. I am using css file for styling which i got from the front developers. I am using application.html  " ".

Whenever i deploy the new changes to customers it still have old css and clients not intrested in the cleaning the history.

I can do manually to change file like main.css?version=1.2 but I am looking automated process.

Can you please suggest me?

Comment: I think http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053531/how-to-handle-caching-of-gwt-theme-css-files?rq=1 give you a response.

Comment: css files not compatable with the resourcebundle it is giving lot of errors.

Comment: But in the linked response they are not using a resource bundle.

Comment: I tried with linked response ,but the libarary not found the method "generateStylesheetInjector". It seems that response previous GWT . I am using GWT 2.5 version.

Comment: The method in 2.5.1 is now in ResourceInjectionUtil class. The class is used as utility class from the SelectionScriptLinker linker. The linked response can't be used with latest version of GWT.